# Ember/Emberfire + Firebase 3 Acceptance Test

Tags: ember.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, emberfire

Prior to firebase 3 update our acceptance test have been running without any issues. We use the following in our *beforeTest* and *afterTest*

```
moduleForAcceptance('Acceptance | Dashboard | Items | Library | New', {
  beforeEach() {
    stubFirebase();
    var ref = createOfflineRef(basicDataRef, 'https://MY-APP.firebaseio.com');
    replaceAppRef(this.application, ref);
    stubValidSession(this.application, {uid: 'xxxx'});
  },
  afterEach() {
    unstubFirebase();
  }
});
```

basicDataRef is a fixture for the test.  The above code allows my to mock session following the test-helper in torii library to allow my application to correctly obtain the data needed as my firebase hieararchy is as follows:
    /
    +--uid
       +--profile
       +--otherdata

I am not testing for permission rules, just interaction to save/edit data in the application, and this has worked OK prior to firebase 3 migration. After version 3 all my test returns the following:

```
    actual: >
        false
    expected: >
        true
    stack: >
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:4130:12
            at exports.default._emberTestingAdaptersAdapter.default.extend.exception (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:49473:7)
            at onerrorDefault (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:41461:24)
            at Object.exports.default.trigger (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:62212:11)
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:63463:40
            at Queue.invoke (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:10415:16)
    message: >
        Error: permission_denied at /xxxx/profile: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
```

I always thought the createOfflineRef in emberfire allows us to bypass rules checking. the fact that it keeps returning permission_denied is quite perplexing. Maybe i need to re-engineer the test? Or I approach this wrongly all this time? Any input is greatly appreciated

Comment: An educated guess: did you create a project in the new Firebase console (firebse.google.com). If that's the case, the new database's security rules are different from the previous project. See the first blue box on https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data.

Comment: Yes I have migrated the project to the new console. The test runs ok with even if I use v2 interface on the migrated project.  But we want to make use of the new storage capabilities of firebase, hence the migration to v3.  I did some digging around and I think the error  has something to do with replaceAppRef not replacing reference in all instances, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got to the bottom of this, and I guess I'll answer my own questions in case somebody else experience the same issue as I have.

the new firebase [InitializeApp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase#.initializeApp)  method has an additional optional parameter called **name**. By default, [Emberfire service](https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/blob/master/addon/services/firebase.js) sets this name to be:

```
export const DEFAULT_NAME = '[EmberFire default app]';
```

However the [Emberfire test helper](https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/blob/master/test-support/helpers/create-offline-ref.js) to create firebase offline ref stubs the firebase instance with a different instance name to be:

```
export const DEFAULT_NAME = '[EmberFire offline test app]';
```

This cause my test to fail with *permission denied*, as the acceptance test is attempting to connect to the '[EmberFire default app]' and the stubbed offline reference is called something else.

Creating my own create-offline-ref helper substituting the DEFAULT_NAME to '[EmberFire default app]' solves the problem.  I'm not sure as to what is the best practice for acceptance test as the change seems deliberate on emberfire.